# Storing data from the keyboard to an array while ignoring duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

So I have a program that I'm working on as an assignment, and part of the requirement is asking me to call a method that retrieve numbers from the user, and storing them into an `array` of size `20`. I have to do this while not including any duplicate values in the array, and I will continue storing the users numbers until the array is full, or the user has entered a negative value. I'm running into a couple of issues.

1. The user has to be able to enter data through multiple lines of text (using the 'enter' key) without interruption, for example:

   `Enter the integers for the array:
   1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
   17 18 18 18 18 18 19
   20`

   That should store: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20` into the array without duplicate values. The program didn't accept any other values because `20` unique digits had been entered, which filled the array.
   I've tried to use different options such as `nextInt()`, `nextLine()`, and even storing the numbers as a List and then converting but I'm having so many issues.

So my question is, how do I allow the user to enter values across multiple lines of input as well as checking if the current value in the keyboard buffer is duplicate/negative, so I can know to skip that value in the buffer or end the program?

I'll include my code, but honestly I've tried reworking this so many times that it's an absolute mess. Any help will be more than welcomed.

```
    public static int getData(int [] set){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the integers for the array.");
    System.out.println("The program will stop accepting values when you enter a negative number or reach the 20 unique limit.");

    int usrInput=keyboard.nextInt(), arraySizeUsed = 0;

    for(int position = 0; position < 20; ) { 

        if(!Arrays.asList(set).contains(usrInput)) {
            if(usrInput > -1) {

                set[position] = usrInput;
                position++;
                arraySizeUsed++;
            }

            else {
                return arraySizeUsed;
            }
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return arraySizeUsed;
}
```

I don't think I should use 'continue' in the loop as I just want to keep the position from incrementing in the case that the current number in the keyboard buffer is already in the array. What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you store value in HashSet and use negative and 20 as sentinel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution using a int array and a direct comparison search.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberScanner {

    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 20;

    static int[] intArray = new int[MAX_SIZE];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int value = 0;
        int size = 0; // Not an array counter, starts at 1. 0 means empty.

        System.out.println("Enter a series of positive integers on one or more lines. Enter a negative number to quit.");

        // Loop until a negative number is found or the MAX_SIZE is reached
        while (size < MAX_SIZE) {
            value = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (value < 0)
                break;

            boolean found = false;
            if (value >= 0 && size > 0) {
                // Add the value to the array
                // First, check if its already there
                for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
                    if (intArray[i] == value) {
                        found = true;
                        break;  // Stop the loop
                    }                   
                }
            }
            if (!found) {               
                intArray[size] = value;
                size++;
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            System.out.printf(intArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<>();
    Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    do {
        int in = sc.nextInt();
        if(in>0 && count < 20) {
            values.add(in);
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }while(sc.hasNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
int position = 0;
while (position < 20) {
   int next = keyboard.nextInt();
   if (next < 0) {
      break; // Negative so exit loop and return
   }

   if (!ArrayUtils.contains(set, next)) {
      set[position] = next;
      position++;
   }

return set;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. For some reason, this code doesn't account for duplicates and continues to add them to the array regardless